# R Dataframe Detecting Hidden Repeated Patterns by Group

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a dataframe looks like below:

```
person   year   location     rank
Harry    2002   Los Angeles  1
Harry    2006   Boston       1
Harry    2006   Los Angeles  2
Harry    2006   Chicago      3

Peter    2001   New York     1
Peter    2002   New York     1

Lily     2005   Springfield  1
Lily     2007   New York     1
Lily     2008   Boston       1
Lily     2011   Chicago      1
Lily     2011   New York     2

Sam      2005   Springfield  1
Sam      2007   New York     1
Sam      2008   Boston       1
Sam      2008   Springfield  2
Sam      2008   New York     3
Sam      2011   Chicago      1
Sam      2011   Springfield  2
```

I want to know at person level, who has a location with rank=1 in a certain year and this location reappears in the next available year but rank!=1. For example, the output should look like:

```
person   yes/no
Harry    1
Peter    0
Lily     0
Sam      1
```

Comment: Why is Lily/NY a 0 for 2007-2011, but Harry/LA a 1 for 2002-2006? Is "next available year" defined at the person level but not the person/location level?

Comment: Thanks for asking. yes, "next available year" defined at the person level but not the person/location level

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an approach with `dplyr`, probably could be more concise.

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
  # define year_number as a count of unique years [assumes sorted already]
  group_by(person) %>%
  mutate(year_num = cumsum(year != lag(year, default = 0))) %>%

  # check for successive years with different ranks
  group_by(person, location) %>%
  mutate(next_yr_switch = year_num == lag(year_num, default = -Inf) + 1 & rank != lag(rank)) %>%
  group_by(person) %>%
  summarize(`yes/no` = sum(next_yr_switch))


## A tibble: 4 x 2
#  person `yes/no`
#* <chr>     <int>
#1 Harry         1
#2 Lily          0
#3 Peter         0
#4 Sam           1
```